# Rails - Rate Limiting a Model's Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking to see if there is a smart way to do something like the following...

In my app I have projects. I want to prevent a user from adding more than 10 projects. My understand after only having used rails for a few weeks is, that I should make a helper in my model for this, does that sound right?

Also should I do this at the model/helper level or is this something that should be done for all models with some type of setting file?

So the idea is, when the user goes to create a new project, before_create, it checks, if the user has 10+ projects already, is says, sorry not at this time? ALso, interested in how to output the error msg, but 1 step at a time for a newbie.

thanks

Comment: If theres no builtin validator you can make a custom one.

Comment: ah very interesting. IN the model? How do you send back an error message with a validator? can you give a light example to kick start me?

Answer (score 3):

Doing this as a validation method is pretty straightforward. In Rails 3 you just declare a method to be run during validation and it has an opportunity to add errors if the situation arises:

```
class Project
  validate :user_can_create_projects

protected
  def user_can_create_projects
    if (user and user.projects.count >= 10)
      errors.add_to_base("You have created too many projects.")
    end
  end
end
```

This is not an entirely bullet-proof method as there is a very small chance that someone might be able to create a project between the interval when you check the count and when you actually create the project. That sort of thing has a much greater chance of happening when someone double-clicks a form submit button, for instance, but in practice is relatively rare.

Comment: very cool, so simple and elegant. I love it. But, I'm using Devise for authentication. And current_user isn't available in the model, so what does one do to get user?

Comment: You need an association you can follow, or you need to create an `attr_accessor :user` simply for this purpose. In your controller you'd assign it accordingly. You can also do a validation like this in the controller if you have more information available in that context. A `user.can_create_more_projects?` method might work better.

Comment: What does attr_accessor :user do, no much on it via Google. Also for the Controller idea, when I do "Current_User.can_create_more_projects?" In the controller, is that using the can_create_more_projects def in the Controller or does it still live in the model, just being accessed by the controller? thanks!

Comment: In the controller, is it private or protected? Do I do the check as a before_filter or in the actual create method? thxs!

Comment: You should make all utility methods in your controller `protected` or they may inadvertently be exposed as possible actions you can route to. You should define a `can_create_more_projects?` method on the user model itself as a public method that simply evaluates: `self.projects.count < 10` Always check your API documentation: [APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails)